# Cordova XMLHttpRequest failing on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, asp.net-core

I've having a problem getting a response from a RESTful API using XMLHttpRequest from an Android device.

The API is written in .NET Core 2.0 and is hosted on my development machine using IIS. My Android device is on the same network as the development machine and can access the API service using Chrome.

I'm hooking into the onreadystatechange method of the XMLHttpRequest object to retrieve the response, but am getting a status value of 0 and a response value of "". When I run the app in a browser simulator everything works fine.

I have the Cordova Whitelist plugin installed, with the following in the config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
```

I have given the app permissions to access the internet in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have ensured that the API service supports CORS, using the following setup:

```
app.UseCors(
    c =>
        {
            c.AllowAnyHeader();
            c.AllowAnyMethod();
            c.AllowAnyOrigin();
        });
```

(This complete disregard for security will not remain!)

This results in responses from the server with the following headers when a request is send via Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
content-length: 49
content-type: application/json
server: Kestrel
access-control-allow-origin: *
request-context: appId=cid-v1:
date: Tue, 28 Nov 2017 10:36:39 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive

{"status":"success"}
```

I've hooked my Android device into use Fiddler and I can see traffic from Chrome being captured, but running my app does not show any requests being made, so I assume the request is being blocked by something before it's being sent.

Does anyone have any ideas please? Any help or suggestions would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just worked out what was blocking the request; it was the Content-Security-Policy meta tag in the html page itself.

I've changed it to the one from the whitelist plugin documentation (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/):

```
<!-- This policy allows everything (eg CSS, AJAX, object, frame, media, etc) except that 
    * CSS only from the same origin and inline styles,
    * scripts only from the same origin and inline styles, and eval()
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I hope this helps someone... or more likely me in 6 months when I've forgotten all about this :)

Comment: @pxaml index.html around the script tag to include cordova.js